# Properly typing Apollo Mutation render prop for onClick handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am currently attempting to rewrite the HowToGraphQL tutorial in TypeScript and have created a custom mutation class with corresponding query as follows:

```
export const postMutation = gql`
    mutation PostMutation($description: String!, $url: String!) {
        post(description: $description, url: $url) {
            id
            createdAt
            url
            description
        }
    }
`;

export interface PostMutationData {
    post: {
        id: string;
        createdAt: string;
        url: string;
        description: string;
    };
}

export interface PostMutationVariables {
    description: string;
    url: string;
}

export class PostMutation extends Mutation<PostMutationData, PostMutationVariables> {}
```

The component that consumes the mutation basically looks like this:

```
<PostMutation mutation={postMutation} variables={{ description, url }}>
    {(onMutate) => <button onClick={onMutate}>Submit</button>}
</PostMutation>
```

Unfortunately the compiler is complaining and saying that I cannot assign `onMutate` to `onClick` with the following error messages:

```
Type 'MutationFn<PostMutationData, PostMutationVariables>' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'options' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>' has no properties in common with type 'MutationOptions<PostMutationData, PostMutationVariables>'.
```

I'd like to know how to assign the `onMutate` handler to `onClick` properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onMutate function is expecting an object parameter called 'options' as its first argument. You are trying to assign that to onClick, which has an event type as its first parameter, which makes the types incompatible.

There are a few ways to fix this. You could create a function that calls onMutate with the option parameter before you declare the button and simply pass said function to onClick.

```
<PostMutation mutation={postMutation}>
    {(onMutate) => {
        const onMutateFunc = () => onMutate({ variables: { description, url } })
        return (
            <button onClick={onMutateFunc}>Submit</button>}
        )
     }
</PostMutation>
```

Or you could create an onClick function that calls onMutate.

```
// Class level function
onClick = () => onMutate({ variables: { description, url } })

<PostMutation mutation={postMutation}>
    {(onMutate) => {
        const onMutateFunc = onMutate({ variables: { description, url } })
        return (
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>Submit</button>}
        )
    }
</PostMutation>
```

You could also just do this inline

```
<PostMutation mutation={postMutation}>
    {(onMutate) => {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => onMutate({ variables: { description, url } })}>Submit</button>}
        )
    }
</PostMutation>
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic: I would advise against using the third variant due to render performance issues since the component gets re-rendered as the anonymous function is recreated. Nonetheless I'll give the first snippet a try.

Comment: Yeah, I have heard of that as well.